# kubeadm with admission webhooks

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have the following conf

```
cat kubeadm-conf.yaml 

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: InitConfiguration
apiServerExtraArgs:
  enable-admission-plugins: NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook
networking:
  podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
```

but, when I do

```
ps -aux | grep admission
root     20697  7.4  2.8 446916 336660 ?       Ssl  03:49   0:21 kube-apiserver --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --advertise-address=10.0.2.15 --allow-privileged=true --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction

I only see the NodeRestriction
```

Please, let me know if anyone can help me make sure that the admission-webhook is indeed running on my cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, even that works, posting the kubeadm answer just in case anyone needs it, following is the right kubeadm config:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
networking:
  podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    enable-admission-plugins: "NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `MutatingAdmissionWebhook` and `ValidatingAdmissionWebhook` have not being properly propagated through api-server as per your provided outputs.

I suggest to proceed with the following steps to achieve your goal:

1. Check and edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` manifest file by adding required admission control plugins to `enable-admission-plugins` Kubernetes API server flag:

> --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,DefaultStorageClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook

2. Delete current `kube-apiserver` Pod and wait until Kubernetes will respawn the new one with reflected changes:

`kubectl delete pod <kube-apiserver-Pod> -n kube-system`

Hope it will help you, I've successfully checked these steps on my environment.

More information about Kubernetes Admission Controllers you can find in the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/).